# D3.JS ForeignObject not rendering in IE and Firefox

Tags: d3.js, svg

As per the guidance I have read, in order to add any html elements in D3.JS SVG we need to create ForeignObjects. So I added a  tag using foreign object and its working just fine in Chrome. Below is the code I am using.

```
this.g.append('svg:foreignObject')
.attr('font-size', "15px")
.attr('x', x - 10)
.attr('y', y - 55)
.append("xhtml:div")
.html('<div class="terst">some text</div></div>')
```

My problem is, it is not rendered in IE and Firefox. Could you please let me know if I miss anything obvious.

Comment: IE doesn't support foreignobject. See compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, have realized ForeignObject is not supported or having issues with IE and Firefox. So decided to change my implementation so it can be supported by all browsers.

Comment: How did you changed your implementation. I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

- [IE does not support foreignObject](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreignObject).
- Firefox requires foreignObject to have width and height attributes

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks for the response. So what is the solution to add html elements to SVG?

Comment: For IE do it the other way round, write a html page and embed SVG in it.

Comment: I already have a html page which has SVG element. Could you please show me a working sample or share any reference link?